# Avoid CORS while calling SHAREPOINT REST API

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I've created VS project - Sharepoint add in (sharepoint-hosted). Im trying to call sp rest api from js ajax, code below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://MYSITE/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Kontrahenci')/items",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    success: function (data) {
        var results = data.d.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
            console.log(data.d.results[i].Title);
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

But i cannot do that, im always getting error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://MYSITE/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Kontrahenci')/items.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin
>   'http://app-802ce2286e9d83.MYSITE' is therefore
>   not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Ofc MYSITE = my url address.

I can connect via browser to url from ajax, and after authorizing (login,password from sharepoint) im getting data.

I also added in app.manifest permissions for Lists(read, and selecting list while building app) and full-control for Web.

When im enable chrome sth like that it works:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="D:\chrome"

But its not a solve of this problem.

Comment: `Avoid CORS` - you can't avoid CORS, CORS is a security measure to stop cross origin resource stealing - you need to use CORS properly, the server needs to know how to give permission when appropriate

Comment: So is there any way to call rest api?

Comment: Yes of course. If it's a cross origin call you have to use CORS properly

Comment: So how can i call? It's not working what did I paste.

Comment: SERVER needs to send proper and appropriate CORS headers. As I mentioned in 1st comment

Comment: Client code never sends CORS headers. Browser adds headers when required for you. Client never should send response headers as client sends a request not a response

Comment: Ok, thanks for you answers, it will help me in the future, now i resolve problem by using SP.executor